# jQuery Tokeninput section header

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I'd like to know if it would be possible to define section headers (a kind of disabled title item that would headline following results) on the result list of a tokeninput search?

I've tried to do it this way, but it's just a workaround and it doesn't behave like I would expect:

```
onResult         : function (results) {
            var currentCategory = '';
            $.each(results, function (index, value) {
                if (value.category != currentCategory) {
                    results.splice(index, 0, {name : value.category});
                    currentCategory = value.category;
                }
            });
            return results;
        },
resultsFormatter: function(item){
            if (!item.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
                return "<li class='header-list-token-input'>" + item.name + "</li>";
            } else {
                return "<li>" + item.name + "</li>";
            }
        }
```

Is there any option in the plugin allowing this feature?

Any help would be much appreciated !